# ## error denied requested access to the resource in Azure pipeline Task

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile, docker-registry

> error denied requested access to the resource in azure pipeline's task "BuildAndPush"

Its happening while pushing the image to the docker repo. I have created the service connection for this and its working fine as I have Tested in the pipeline itself.

Dockerhub - gunjandavid1/mvnrepo

```
- task: Docker@2   inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'Dockerhub Registry'
    repository: 'mvnrepo'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'consumerBanking/Dockerfile'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue as I was not giving the proper repo path as per the docker hub "gunjandavid1/mvnrepo"

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'Dockerhub Registry'
    repository: 'gunjandavid1/mvnrepo'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'consumerBanking/Dockerfile'
```